# When does the implicit type conversion take place during an assignment

Tags: c++, casting

If got the following code:

```
uint8_t value   = 0xF0;
uint16_t shift  = 0x10;
uint32_t result = value << shift;

cout << "The Result is: " << result << endl;
```

I expected that the the output to be 0 but instead it was 15728640.

My Questions

- Isn't the expresion evaluated => 0 and after that implicitly converted
  to the type of result?
- Is this behaviour standard?
- Where can I get further information about this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `value << shift`, `value` is implicitly converted to `int` before the shift.  This is called "integer promotion".  No other rules apply to this particular case.

Integer promotion applies to any type whose range fits within an `int`.  If it can't fit in an `int`, then `unsigned int` is tried.  If it can't fit in either, then integer promotion does nothing.

For more information... well, I just read the spec.

Answer (score 1):

A shift operation involves an "integer promotion", which means to convert types narrower than int to int. The promotion is done before the shift, so the behavior you are seeing is expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a 32 or 64 bit word machine, the shift will be in a 32 or 64 bit register.  That is, the 8 bit "value" is loaded into the register, shifted, and then (if necessary) truncated to the final variable.

That's why the length of "int" is implementation dependent.